# Locate server on LAN in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, networking, web-applications

**TL;DR**

In Javascript, how do you to find the IP of all servers running a specified program on a specified port in the LAN?

**Background**

I'm writing a server in node.js that is supposed to connect users browsers as controllers to a common device on which a game is running. The browsers are running a web app based on html and Javascript. The connection is based on socket.io.

I'd like for the web app to be able to find all available instances of this server in the LAN in order to create a server list for the user to choose from.

Is there a way to make the server discoverable by the web app on the local network in Javascript, and in that case: how?

**Ideas**

- Have the server broadcast its IP to all devices on the LAN and have the web app listen for these messages (No idea how to do this without node on the client)
- Connect to every IP on the network and see if the connection is successful. (Does not seem feasible)
- Scan every IP on the network and connect only to those where the port is open. (Once again, no idea how to do this without node on the client and does not seeem feasible either.)

**EDIT**

The server is supposed to be portable and work independently, without any central system backing it up or providing matchmaking for clients. It is a LAN only server and should work even without internet access.

Comment: Instead of all this, why dont you make a server which listens to all the clients and transmits the client list to all other clients like bittorrent protocol. or you can use gcm for chrome.

Comment: I don't really see how this would change anything as you'd still have to find the server in the first place? Or do you mean like a central server for all sessions that would then figure out who are on the same network and connect those?

Comment: yes there is always a central server in bit torrent protocol.

Comment: Well, then it would not suit my needs I'm afraid. This is for a portable multiplayer server. I'll update my question.

Comment: Hey Felix, have you found a solution that works?

Comment: No, I ended up having the server tell me its IP via the terminal and having to enter the IP manually on connect

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you do this. Sorry. Since there is no exposure to UDP on client-side JavaScript, broadcasting is out of question. Any attempt on massive scanning will quickly raise flags on network monitoring software. You have to use a known address.

Comment: Well, that's depressing. I'll keep the question open a while longer just in case though.